# A global variable as a method argument in the same java class: Is this bad programming practice?

Tags: java, global-variables, parameter-passing

Below code works just fine. But as a newbie I'm not sure if it's bad practice to pass the global variables into the private method as an argument in the same java class. Is this acceptable? Is there a better or more acceptable way to do it, in case this is bad programming?

```
@Value("${canDeleteAllBefore:true}")
private boolean canDeleteAllBefore;
@Value("${canDeleteAllAfter:false}")
private boolean canDeleteAllAfter;
@Value("${canExecute:true}")
private boolean canExecute;   
public ConsoleApp(@Value("${canDeleteAllBefore:true}") String canDeleteAllBefore,
                             @Value("${canDeleteAllAfter:true}") String canDeleteAllAfter,
                             @Value("${canExecute:true}") String canExecute) {
   
    setboolean(canDeleteAllBefore, "canDeleteAllBefore", this.canDeleteAllBefore);
    setboolean(canDeleteAllAfter, "canDeleteAllAfter",this.canDeleteAllAfter);
    setboolean(canExecute, "canExecute",this.canExecute);
}
private void setboolean(String booleanValue, String propertyName, boolean boolValue) {
    if (booleanValue.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || booleanValue.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
        boolValue = Boolean.parseBoolean(booleanValue);
    } 

    else {
        System.out.println(booleanValue + " is not a boolean value. " +
                "Please use either true or false as a value for the property " + propertyName);
        System.exit(1);
    }
   }
```

Comment: your code does strange things. I think it's better to give a more realistic example:  variable propertyName is not used, variable `condition` is missing, and settings `boolValue` does nothing, because it has no further usages. I hope you're not expecting that this `booleanValue =` modifies the value of your class-level field. Because it won't. It just acts locally on the parameter value.

Comment: @bvdb, l tried to shorten and give a concise version of my code. I will add the parts. sorry for the confusion

Comment: I hope my answer clarifies something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the expectancy is that the `setboolean` method will change the value of the `canExecute` field, then that's unfortunately not correct.

So when you call this line

```
setboolean(canExecute, "canExecute",this.canExecute)
```

It will actually take the current value of `this.canExecute` and will pass it in. The method `setboolean` does not know where that value comes from.

So when `setboolean` updates the value of the parameter, it won't have any effect outside the scope of that function.

So, in your case, what would make more sense is:

```
private boolean setboolean(String booleanValue, String propertyName, boolean boolValue) {
    if (booleanValue.equalsIgnoreCase("true") || booleanValue.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
        return Boolean.parseBoolean(booleanValue);
    } 
    throw new Exception("invalid value");
}
```

And then use the function like  `this.canExecute = setboolean(...);` Just using the return value of the function.

There is another way. You may want to look at `BooleanHolder`, which acts like a wrapper around a primitive boolean. The advantage is that you can pass it around and change the content of the holder. That's close to what you attempted to do.

Comment: i understand the problem in my code. Thank you! Your solution is not exactly how l wanted to do. But probably how l should do it. :))

Comment: @armel I added one more alternative, which may interest you.

Comment: @bvdp, that is actually what I had in mind. Thank you so much! :)